# Zend Db Deprecated?

Tags: magento2.4.6, zend-framework

We're just updating our development site from 2.4.6-p3 to 2.4.6-p4.
One of our modules seems to prevent a reindex from being completed.
The error is:

```
Error: Class "Zend\Db\Sql\Select" not found in /home/site/public/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Indexer/Bestseller.php:193
```

Line 193 is: `$select->reset(Select::COLUMNS)->columns($columns);`

I presume Zend_Db has been deprecated and moved to Laminas like previous updates?

I have tried replacing:

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
```

with

```
use Laminas\Db\Sql\Sql;
```

And instances of

```
new \Zend_Db_Expr
```

with

```
new \Laminas\Db\Sql\Expression
```

But then I recieve the error:

```
Error: Class "Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\Select" not found in /home/site/public/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Indexer/Bestseller.php:195
```

Any idea what changes need to be made here?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems using: `use Laminas\Db\Sql\Select;` or `Magento\Framework\DB\Select;`

and leaving `new \Zend_Db_Expr` as it is allows a reindex.
I'm assuming that can't be correct usage though?